# Grails write different level logs to file

Tags: grails, logging

I have a problem with logging in Grails. How do I go about writing logs into file? and in addition I would like different level log to go into different file?

Also is there are settings for production and development logging? For example if I am running project in development, there is no catalina.out, where will log file be going?

**Example:**

```
log.info "I am working fine look: ..."
```

Information I would like to go into lets say info.log

```
log.error "Bad coding results in: ..."
```

Error I would like to go into standard Tomcat log: catalina.out

```
log.debug "Debugging is a pain: ..."
log.fatal "Just died because..."
```

And the rest of log levels I would like to go into fine.log

Thank you very much.

P.S: Examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: The grails documentation has a pretty good section about logging, i think you can find all your answers there http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging

Comment: @enterlezi you should have added this as an answer :)

Comment: I dont think a single link is an answer. Feel free to use it and provide a complete answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is (relatively) simple. You need to first set the log level, then activate it, then write to it. 
So standard is that log level ERROR is on, so anything written using log.error "" will send a meesage to stdout (if you have not change appenders behaviour)

Below is the changes if you want your application to display Error, Warn and Info but not debug.

In Config.groovy under log4j, lets change the appenders to tell us who's talking (Kind of super charged it of someone else's setting

```
appenders {
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{[dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} %-5p %c %x - %m%n')
}
```

Then we change log level on our app to "info" (So will write Error, Warn and Info for our app), after appenders before error add the line

```
info 'grails.app'
```

Lastly, lets try with some code, so in any controller or similar, add the following three lines

```
 log.debug "First piggy wrote to Debug"
 log.info "Second piggy wrote to Info"
 log.error "And the third piggy wrote to Error"
```

And my console says:

```
[22.10.13 10:37:43.446] INFO  grails.app.controllers.crmapper.CrMapperController  - Second piggy wrote to Info
[22.10.13 10:37:43.446] ERROR grails.app.controllers.crmapper.CrMapperController  - And the third piggy wrote to Error
```